# Async and Await function not working properly

Tags: javascript, async-await

I seem to be running into an issue with my async and await functions not working and I am relatively new to this...

When I call the CallToPopulateCustomerDropDown, I never get to the call for SetCustomerMultiColumnAfterAddingNewCustomerFromNewOrder ( I know this because I have break point here in it and it never gets hit). So I am figuring that I have written something wrong

Here is my code

```
async function CallToPopulateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue) {
        await CallPopulateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue);
        SetCustomerMultiColumnAfterAddingNewCustomerFromNewOrder();
}

function CallPopulateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue) {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            LogCallStackToConsole('populateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue)');
            //#region Variable Declarations

            let orderField, grid, ds, foundCatalog, dd;

            //#endregion

            for (i = 0; i < CustomersList.length; i++) {
                if (CustomersList[i].Company.length == 0) {
                    CustomersList[i].Company = CustomersList[i].FirstName + " " + CustomersList[i].LastName
                }
            }

            $(ddlCustomer).empty();

            $(ddlCustomer).kendoMultiColumnComboBox({
                placeholder: "Select Customer...",
                dataTextField: "Company",
                dataValueField: "CustomerID",
                height: 300,
                columns: [
                    { field: "FirstName", title: "First", width: 200 },
                    { field: "LastName", title: "Last", width: 200 },
                    { field: "Company", title: "Company", width: 200 }
                ],
                footerTemplate: "#: instance.dataSource.total() # Customers Found",
                filter: "contains",
                filterFields: ["FirstName", "LastName", "Company"],
                dataSource: {
                    data: CustomersList,
                    sort: [
                        { field: "FirstName", dir: "asc" },
                        { field: "LastName", dir: "asc" },
                        { field: "Company", dir: "asc" }
                    ]
                },
                change: function () {

                },
                select: function (e) {
                    LogCallStackToConsole('populateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue).select');
                    orderField = $('#txtOrderName').val();
                    grid = $('#gridNewOrder').getKendoGrid();
                    ds = grid.dataSource.view();
                    foundCatalog;
                    for (let i = 0; i < ds.length; i++) {
                        if (ds[i].Catalog.length > 0) {
                            foundCatalog = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (orderField.length > 0 && foundCatalog) {
                        $('#btnOK').prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                }
            });
            if (selectedValue != null) {
                dd = $(ddlCustomer).data("kendoMultiColumnComboBox");
                dd.value(selectedValue);
            }
        });
        resolve();
    }
    catch (err) {
        reject();
    }
}

function SetCustomerMultiColumnAfterAddingNewCustomerFromNewOrder() {
    let customerMultiColumn = $('#ddlCustomer').data("kendoMultiColumnComboBox");
    customerMultiColumn.select(function (dataItem) {
        return dataItem.Company === g_CustomerEditorObject.companyName;
    });
    ResetGlobalObject(g_CustomerEditorObject);
}
```

Comment: What do "not working properly" and "an issue" mean? Please specifically describe what you are trying to do and what isn't working

Comment: @AndyRay, Let me go on an make an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortening your code, you're doing this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
});
resolve();
```

Note how you're calling `resolve()` *outside* of the Promise callback function block, meaning your code doesn't have access to it. You're also doing the same with `catch()`, you're using it outside of the function it's available in. If you want to learn more about this, you can research "Javascript scope."

You're probably trying to do this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        LogCallStackToConsole('populateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue)');
        ...
        resolve();
    }
    catch (err) {
        reject();
    }
});
```

However, your code isn't actually doing anything asynchronous, so you don't need a promise here, at least not in this implementation. A promise is meant to handle a function that finishes "later", like a network call. Your function appears to execute synchronously like a regular Javascript function. There's no callback or operation you're waiting for.

Comment: I was trying to wait for the CallPopulateCustomerDropDown to load and then run SetCustomerMultiColumnAfterAddingNewCustomerFromNewOrder, thats why i figured an async and await would work. The SetCustomerMultiColumnAfterAddingNewCustomerFromNewOrder wasn't setting properly so I thought that this might be the way.. Did I missunderstand that an async await would work for this scenario?

Comment: Javascript executes synchronously, top to bottom, single threaded, it's "blocking," so your functions will run in order. Async / promises are for when you want to handle something that finishes much later. Your function isn't doing anything asynchronous, so there's nothing to wait for. Promises/async are a challenging concept and take some time to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `resolve` outside of the promise

Also, it's sort of bad design to try catch a promise if the function is returning the promise. The code calling the function should try/catch the returned promise, like so:

```
async function CallToPopulateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue) {

    try{
        await CallPopulateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue);
        SetCustomerMultiColumnAfterAddingNewCustomerFromNewOrder();
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}

function CallPopulateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        LogCallStackToConsole('populateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue)');
        // ....the rest of your code

        // if you code has a problem, you can choose to reject
        // return reject('the reason')

        resolve()
    });
}
```